# Many to many hibernate with struts 1 : illegal argument exception

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many, struts-1

I am using Struts 1 with hibernate.
After adding many to many relation in my hibernate entity, save does not works with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1776)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1762)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1651)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1680)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1039)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:796)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1192)
at org.broker.web.CustomizedActionServlet.process(CustomizedActionServlet.java:522)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:430)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.broker.web.UnicodeFilter.doFilter(UnicodeFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.broker.web.MessageFilter.doFilter(MessageFilter.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.broker.util.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:19)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

my addition in .hbm.xml:

```
 <set name="customerGroupsForReport" table="APPUSER_CUSTOMER_GROUP_REPORT"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="APPUSER_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="org.broker.model.CustomerGroup">
            <column name="CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

in .java entity

```
 private Set <CustomerGroup> customerGroupsForReport = new HashSet<CustomerGroup>(0);
    public Set<CustomerGroup> getCustomerGroupsForReport() {
        return customerGroupsForReport;
    }

    public void setCustomerGroupsForReport(Set<CustomerGroup> customerGroupsForReport) {
        this.customerGroupsForReport = customerGroupsForReport;
    }
```

in .jsp:

```
 <html:select property="appUser.customerGroupsForReport" multiple="true">
               <html:options collection="customerGroups" labelProperty="customerGroupName" property="customerGroupId"/>
          </html:select>
```

in action class:

```
        request.setAttribute("customerGroups", manager.findObjects(CustomerGroup.class,"customerGroupName"));
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: It looks like there is binding issue of request parameter  "appUser.customerGroupsForReport" to its corresponding property in your  ActionForm...can you please show your ActionForm

Comment: I am using DynaActionForm

Answer (score 1):

As you are using multi select dropdown,
Assuming customerGroupId is numeric and user has selected 1 and 2 customerGroupId
appUser.customerGroupsForReport parameter will be passed as
appUser.customerGroupsForReport= 1
appUser.customerGroupsForReport= 2

Considering Above ,I would suggest you to bind "customerGroupsForReport" property to array in your DynaActionForm Configuration e.g. Long[] (if your customerGroupId is long)
And Then convert back to Set in your Action class.

Comment: what is your reason ? Is there any document from struts?

Comment: I have just Updated my answer

Comment: There is not any hibernate solution?